# Android- keep user logged in to AWS Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have problem with keeping user logged in to AWS Cognito in my android app. This is the code which checks that:

```
CognitoUser user = AppHelper.getPool().getCurrentUser();

username = user.getUserId();

if(username != null) {
     AppHelper.setUser(username);
     inUsername.setText(user.getUserId());
     user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes (I guess after some time) the app forgets the user and that code:

```
user.getUserId();
```

Returns null. However that is never null:

```
AppHelper.getPool().getCurrentUser();
```

My code basis on the code from the sample app so I cannot understand why it doesn't work. I though that there might be a problem with Cognito pool, so I changed in devices options to always remember user device, but the issue didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz,

`user.getUserId();`  will always return the userid, if the referenced CognitoUser object was created with `CognitoUser user = AppHelper.getPool().getCurrentUser();` after a user had previously successfully signed-in. 
 
An explanation for the behavior you are seeing could be that the `user` was changed to reference a CognitoUser object which was not set to any user.  This can happen when `CognitoUser user = AppHelper.getPool().getCurrentUser();` is executed after clearing app data on the Android device. 
 
Can you give provide any more details about your app, to better understand the issue? When the app executes `user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);`, are you able to successfully sign-in?

Comment: Yes it does handle okay. The only problem is how to log in users whose session has expired after one hour but he returns to the app.